# How to upload a big file on google cloud with wicket

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, wicket

I try to upload a big file on Google cloud with wicket. I use FileUploadField and UploadFile methods. Nevertheless I can only upload small files (less than 10kb). If I upload a bigger file I obtain an exception (java.security.AccessControlException: access denied). I do not have the permission to create a buffer file and write.

```
final FileUploadField FiletoUpload = new FileUploadField("uploadfile", new Model());
    form.add(FiletoUpload);

    form.add(new Button("upload") {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {

            //here we upload
            getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new IRequestHandler() {

                @Override
                public void respond(IRequestCycle irc) {

                    FileUpload uploadedFile = FiletoUpload.getFileUpload();
                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) irc.getResponse().getContainerResponse();

                    InputStream CORPUS = null;
                    try {
                        CORPUS = uploadedFile.getInputStream();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                    try {
                       doGet(null, httpResponse);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Upload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    uploadedFile.closeStreams();
                }

                @Override
                public void detach(IRequestCycle irc) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I do not use blobstore, I use com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.*. I open a channel to write on the cloud.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    GcsService gcsservice = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
    GcsFilename uploadfile = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);
    GcsFileOptions optionsBuilder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
            .mimeType("text/plain")
            .acl("bucket-owner-full-control")
            .build();

    GcsOutputChannel writechannel = gcsservice.createOrReplace(uploadfile, optionsBuilder );

    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int char_read = 0;
    long i;
    for(i=0; i< CORPUSsize; i++){
        char_read = CORPUS.read(); //I read the corpus of the file
        char mychar = (char) char_read;
        buffer.append(mychar);
    }

    writechannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
    writechannel.close();

}
```

Is there a solution to upload a big file without obtaining a permission exception?

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace for your exception?

Answer (score 0):

Wicket uses a DiskFileItemFactory, which stores files on disk after a 10240 bytes threshold.

You have to change the sizeThreshold or uses an alternative implementation of FileItemFactory. See the MultipartServletWebRequestImpl constructor.

Comment: I saw the constructor. How can I use it to change the size?

Comment: Sorry I tried something, but my class extands WebPage and not httpServlet. If I create a WebRequest or a requestcycle i got a problem: it is not a httpservletrequest and it is not multipart. So it is impossible...